# How to access the content of HTTP page from HTTPS page?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, office-365, ajax

I am currently making a sharepoint 2013 app on Indian railways, in this app I am accessing railways api which is on HTTP site and my code is on HTTPS site, which is office 365 online site. Since I am making an app on office 365 it is giving me an error, ' Loading mixed (insecure) active content on a secure page "[http://pnrbuddy.com/api/station_by_code/code/cnb/format/json/pbapikey/539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3/pbapisign/906544ca31f9c0048e80bde8127556af828e313b](http://pnrbuddy.com/api/station%5fby%5fcode/code/cnb/format/json/pbapikey/539ff0f815ca697c681fe01d32ba52e3/pbapisign/906544ca31f9c0048e80bde8127556af828e313b)" ' , in my browser console what would be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really only two ways that you can overcome this and only one of them is controllable by you.

1. The bad answer is that each visitor can change a setting in their browser to allow mixed content. That's just not a practical solution. I'd argue it's just bad all the way around.
2. You will need to use a proxy to get the data for you. You could use the [Proxy API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179895%28v=office.15%29.aspx) available in SharePoint, or you could write a custom proxy service.

Comment: Using the Proxy API is a cool idea. I think you must have an app context though, which I find a bit strange (since it does not have to be app-specific)

Comment: The developer site created on office 365 is not working properly the app is taking time to install when the solution is deployed, so I am using office 365 online, and there I am writing my code in App.js. So can I access Proxy API from there?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to.